# How to modify Kotlin Coroutine Flow value after initialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

## Expected

**Initialize a Kotlin Coroutine Flow and modify its' value after the Flow's creation.**

The desired functionality is similar to MutableLiveData's [`setValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#setValue(T)) which allows data to be added to an existing MutableLiveData object. 
In the example below `setValue` is called on the `_feed` MutableLiveData value in *FeedViewModel.kt* in order to update the value.

This works as expected, emitting the values in *FeedFragment.kt*

*FeedViewState.kt*

```
data class _FeedViewState(
    val _feed: MutableLiveData<List<Tweet>> = MutableLiveData()
)

data class FeedViewState(private val _feedViewState: _FeedViewState) {
    val feed: LiveData<List<Tweet>> = _feedViewState._feed
}
```

*FeedViewModel.kt*

```
class FeedViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {
    private val _feedViewState = _FeedViewState()
    val feedViewState = FeedViewState(_feedViewState)
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            feedRepository.getFeed().collect { results ->
                when (results.status) {
                    LOADING -> ...
                    SUCCESS -> withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        _feedViewState._feed.value = results.data
                    }
                    ERROR -> ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(...): View? {
        viewModel.feedViewState.feed.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ feed ->
                //Do something with the tweets here.
        }        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)
    }
}
```

## Observed

In order to implement the same pattern using Kotlin Coroutines the LiveData in the *FeedViewState.kt* is replaced with Flow. In *FeedViewModel.kt* the desired result is to add data to the `_feed` Flow value. The attempted solutions have been applying `map`, and `emit` inside of `transform` and `onCompletion` to the `_feed` Flow value.

However, this solution does not emit the desired values from the Flow value in *FeedFragment.kt*.

*FeedViewState.kt*

```
data class _FeedViewState(
    val _feed: Flow<List<Tweet>> = flow { }
)

data class FeedViewState(private val _feedViewState: _FeedViewState) {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    val feed: Flow<List<Tweet>> = _feedViewState._feed }
}
```

*FeedViewModel.kt*

```
class FeedViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {
    private val _feedViewState = _FeedViewState()
    val feedViewState = FeedViewState(_feedViewState)
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            feedRepository.getFeed().collect { results ->
                when (results.status) {
                    LOADING -> ...
                    SUCCESS -> withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        _feedViewState._feed.map { results.data!! }
                    }
                    ERROR -> ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(...): View? {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.feedViewState.feed.collect { tweets ->
                //Do something with the tweets here.
            }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) is a newer solution compared to Kotlin Channels that allow mutable updates to the Flow `value` as well as the ability to immutable observe data streams.

Answer (score 1):

Flow is meant to be [self contained](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1448#issuecomment-522529810). What I would suggest is using [ConflatedBroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/) which offers functionality I believe you are looking for but this is currently an experimental feature in kotlin